# How to create bypass mechanism in .netcore service?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a worker service that calls an API call to get some needed answers. sometimes the web service cannot respond and requests will go to timeout mode.

Now I want to develop a Bypass mechanism to bypass the service when service succeeds rate decrease lower than a limitation. now I want a list which will fill with the results of the last specified period of time to calculate the success rate according to those data and bypass the web API call if is needed.

this is my challenge: 
how to Implement my results repo? I have multiple choices

1. List which is not thread-safe and also has no expiration time but is easy to use in query and data structure.
2. MemoryCach has an expiration time limit but we cannot query on its items and we just can add distinct key values.
3. concurrent Generics are concurrent but they have no expiration time and query facility.

are there any other options? and is there any builtin or third-party library for bypass mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for Polly:

> Polly is a .NET resilience and transient-fault-handling library that allows developers to express policies such as Retry, Circuit Breaker, Timeout, Bulkhead Isolation, and Fallback in a fluent and thread-safe manner.

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#resilience-policies